# Gravity Form need a hook when hit the page break button

Tags: gravity-forms-plugin

I have created a multistep form on the Gravity form plugin. Now I want to get the data when I click on each step button. See the image :https://nimb.ws/xW6fYk

I used the page break field. https://nimb.ws/jyEvAL

So now I want to get data each time when I click on each step button. Please help me out the hook name.

Thanks,
Subhankar

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might be looking for the Partial Entries add-on?

https://www.gravityforms.com/add-ons/partial-entries/

If not, you can listen for the [gform_pre_process](https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_pre_process/) hook to see what data is being submitted on each page submission.